# Ubuntu make: 'install' is up to date

Tags: 16.04, nodejs

I'm trying to install node which I've done many times from source but now after doing ./configure and try make install I just get 'make: 'install' is up to date'. How do I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you need to `make clean`?

Comment: @MichaelBay didn't work if I just run 'make' I get *** No rule to make target 'src/ares_cancel.o', needed by 'libcares.a'.  Stop.